# How to set up Django development environment without installing?

Tags: django, ubuntu, path

I'm a student and the lab staff has set up permissions that won't students install software on the machines (or to our profiles).

I'm curious how I can develop Django application in a contained environment. I checked out the Django trunk to my Ubuntu home directory and added the bin path to my .bashrc. But when I try to use django-admin.py, an error occurs:

```
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

I'm quite confident this is simply a path issue. My real question is whether there's a *proper* to do self-contained development or if I need to manually add paths, and which if so.

In advance, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't adding django directory to PYTHONPATH env varialbe help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually set the path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/kevin/dir_with_module')
```

You may also want to look into setting up a virtual environment.  This article has good information:  http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/

Comment: Sure, I could do the same in my bash profile, but it feels so hackish.

Comment: Ah! Now that you've added that link, my question appears answered. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric, your link is dead can you update it please I need it, thank